# c++ custom iterator const conversion done right

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, std

I try to implement the copy constructor of my std compatible custom iterator for a custom container.
The container looks something like this:

```
template <typename T, Alloc>
class container {
    template <typename ValueType>
    class raw_iterator;
    
    ...
    using value_type = T;
    ...

    using iterator = raw_iterator<value_type>
    using const_iterator = raw_iterator<const value_type>
    ...
}
```

The raw_iterator looks something like this:

```
template <typename T, Alloc>
template <typename ValueType>
class container<T, Alloc>::raw_iterator {
    ...
}
```

If i'm right, I have to implement a copy constructor for both, the iterator and const_iterator, such that the iterators can be copied to the same type and a normal iterator can be copied into a const_iterator.
How can this be achieved?

PS: I have to provide some functionality in the copy constructor, so i cant use an implizit generated constructor.

Comment: You can create an implicit constructor for the `const_iterator` which takes an `iterator` as argument. Then everything will "just work".

Comment: as i said, i need to put some logic in the copy constructor not just the automatic generated one. Besides that how would i add such a constructor on just one of the template spetializations?

Comment: Ok, let me try and make an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an implicit constructor for the const_iterator which takes an iterator as argument. Then everything will "just work".

Here's an example of what I think you want:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ValueType>
class raw_iterator {
  public:
    // Typedefs
    using non_const_value_type = std::remove_const_t<ValueType>;
    using const_value_type = std::add_const_t<non_const_value_type>;

    // Constructor - Need extra template argument here to allow SFINAE to work.
    template <class U = ValueType,
      std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U, const_value_type>::value, int> = 0>
    raw_iterator (raw_iterator<non_const_value_type> const & other) {
      // Do stuff.
    }

  private:
    // Friends - Make raw_iterator<X> friend of raw_iterator<X const>
    friend std::conditional_t<
        std::is_same<ValueType, non_const_value_type>::value,
        raw_iterator<const_value_type>, void
      >;
};
```

There's a conditional constructor taking an `raw_iterator<AnythingNonConst>` which only exists if the `raw_iterator`'s own temple type is `AnythingConst`.

Furthermore, `raw_iterator<AnythingNonConst>` is a friend of `raw_iterator<AnythingConst>`, but not the other way around. So you can copy whatever members you want in the conditional constructor.

Here's an online example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/8gDzHyheIrpsTL5y.

Comment: perfekt, so std::enable_if is used to enable/disable the right constructor based on the ValueType?

Comment: Yes, it's using SFINAE to do that. I can't really explain that adequately in a comment, but here's a starting point if you want to know more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error. There's also a ton of blog articles about it. It's a nice trick which very often comes in handy!

Comment: Basically, when `U != const_value_type`, then `std::enable_if_t` is a typedef for a type which actually doesn't exist in the `std::enable_if` class. And due to SFINAE this is not an error, instead the function is simply ignored by the compiler. In this case only when `U == const_value_type` the typedef exists and in that case the compiler takes that constructor into account.

Comment: This is valid in the c++ std or is this a compiler implementation thing?
I guess if this is a pattern its valid in the std...

Comment: Works for all C++ compilers, it's a very "standard" way of doing things. My example code is for C++14, but you can easily make it work for C++11 as well, just need to sprinkle a few `typename`s here and there.